# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when uses images

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

i have one activity that show one image in a image view, if i go back, and go to the activity again application crash with this message:

```
01-08 00:17:18.089: E/AndroidRuntime(12547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 00:17:18.089: E/AndroidRuntime(12547): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-08 00:17:18.089: E/AndroidRuntime(12547):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
01-08 00:17:18.089: E/AndroidRuntime(12547):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
01-08 00:17:18.089: E/AndroidRuntime(12547):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:299)
01-08 00:17:18.089: E/AndroidRuntime(12547):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:324)
01-08 00:17:18.089: E/AndroidRuntime(12547):    at com.rbrlnx.lugares.mostrarLugar.onCreate(mostrarLugar.java:74)
```

The activity is this

```
sFoto=obtainsRealPath(Uri.parse(foto));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sFoto);
ImageView iLugar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iDelLugar);
iLugar.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Is only one image, why is out of memory¿¿

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inSampleSize = 8;

Yes, i put this and now it works fine

Comment: try looking in your full logcat and you'll see that you're being denied space allocation from the dalvik vm. How much is it requesting and how much is available ?

Comment: logcat dont sai me nothing of space, only the code i have pasted up

Comment: you're clearly not looking in the right log then, when you get denied space, there WILL be a log that says dalvik vm just denied your request for memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ImageView.setImageURI()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29) instead:

```
ImageView iLugar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iDelLugar);
iLugar.setImageURI(Uri.parse(foto));
```

If this does not fix the issue than the image is simply too large.

A Bitmap read into memory takes up a lot more space than the raw bits sitting on disk. If you don't need to do any operations on the Bitmap data, simply handing the imageView a Uri (path) to the file is more efficient.